# Number of overlapping elements

Tags: r, vector

I've got two vectors:

```
vec1 <- c(1,0,1,1,1)
vec2 <- c(1,1,0,1,1)
```

The vectors have the same elements at position 1, 4 and 5.

How can I return the number of elements that overlap in 2 vectors taking the position into account? So, here I would like to return the number 3.

Comment: @zx8754 You should add that as an answer

Comment: @James I was hoping the post would be deleted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Test for equality, then `sum`, you might want to exclude `NA`s:

```
sum(vec1==vec2, na.rm=TRUE)
```

**EDIT**
Exclude `0==0` matches, by adding an exclusion like:

```
sum(vec1==vec2 & vec1!=0, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Thanks to @CarlWitthoft

Or, if you have only ones and zeros, then:

```
sum((vec1+vec2)==2, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: And how should I adapt this if I only want to take the elements different from 0 into account?

Comment: @Anita you could add an exclusion like `sum(vec1==vec2 & vec1!=0)` .

Comment: Good edit: your solution is almost certainly faster than mine, but be very careful when dealing with floats rather than integers in general.  For just plain ones and zeros this should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

If your entries are only 0 and 1 (or if you are only interested in 0 and anything that is not 0) you can use xor to determine where they differ and then sum its negation, otherwise you would have to test for equality as @zx8754 commented:

```
sum(!xor(vec1,vec2))
[1] 3
```

Comment: @AnandaMahto Thanks, I overlooked that.

Comment: No problem. It seems like [I was overthinking things](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27380162/r-number-of-overlapping-elements#comment43209908_27380389).